# Remove extra Carriage from the mid of the text file in c#

Tags: c#

Got a text file in which there is a down arrow symbol in the middle of the line and from there the line breaks as you can see in the image. I guess that's  extra carriage return that is coming in the file and i want to remove it from the middle of the line.There is a carriage return by the end of the every line that is fine.I want to create a console application that can read that text file line by line and remove that carriage from the middle and write a new text file having no carriage in the middle of it.

[image]

In the end of the first line of the image there is a down arrow that's the extra carriage coming automatically that I want to remove and write into a new text file.

Comment: You can use yourstring.Replace("\n", string.Empty); to replace all occurances.

Comment: Are you sure it's a real CR-character and not a line-wrap by the editor? What happens when you add a real line break after "Sponsorship"?

Comment: Where did that file come from? Are you sure there is no newline (or CR) in the original data?

Comment: You don't tell us how C# plays into this. Are you creating the file (where is the code)? Reading the file (where is the code)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use following approach that uses [`Char.IsLetterOrDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletterordigit(v=vs.110).aspx) and string methods like `Substring` and `Replace`:

```
char[] chars = text.ToCharArray();
int letterStart = Array.FindIndex(chars, c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
int letterEnd = Array.FindLastIndex(chars, c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
if (letterStart != letterEnd)
{
    string before = text.Remove(letterStart);
    string after = text.Substring(letterEnd);
    string between = text.Substring(letterStart, letterEnd - letterStart);
    string[] lineBreaks = { "\r\n", "\n", "\r" };
    Array.ForEach(lineBreaks, s => between = between.Replace(s, ""));
    text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", before, between, after);
}
```